# How to create grouped Cross Table in Jasper reports in different excel tabs?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

What I have is single cross table shown below whose data is coming from a sub data set.

[image: Single Cross table]

I would like to split this cross table on the basis of column1 and want something of this sort.

[image]

Further, I would like to export these tables in different excel tabs. May be by dynamically adding page break between them (Still figuring out how to  do that as well).Name of these tabs has to based on Column1 i:e type1, type2, type3 etc. How do I dynamically set those names.Lastly, I also have to add this report to a another main report as sub report. Keeping all this in mind. Any help on how do I achieve this sort of format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling alot I was able to do it in this way.

1. Use report Dataset(main) for the crosstab.
2. Create group on Column1. Add footer for it.Remove all other band if you don't want them.
3. Put the break then Crosstab then a dummy Label as shown in the group footer.
       [image]

4.Use it as subreport in different report.

Important Explanations:

Label is basically for naming the exported tab in excel.

`<staticText>
  <reportElement x="0" y="4002" width="100" height="20" uuid="392f134e-746d-46bf-8895-ecb403d54211">
    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN1}]]></propertyExpression>
 </reportElement>
        <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
</staticText>`

Here i utilized the dynamic property expression to name the sheet dynamically and Break to split the sheet in different tab on group to group the data based on column1.

Comment: Hello, do you maybe have full example as jrxml file, i am trying to achieve something similar but struggling..